# Bayesian Game with Asymmetric Information and 2 Players

Tags: game-theory, bayesian, nash-equilibrium

I need some help with the following Bayesian Game. I tried it a few times and watched some tutorials but I just cant figure out how to solve it.

Consider a two player game with this payoff matrix

[image]

where $\theta \in \{0,3\}$ is a parameter known by Player 1. Player 2 believes that $\theta = 0$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ and $\theta  = 3$ with probability $\frac{1}{2}$. Everything above is common knowledge. Player 1 chooses between T and B, Player 2 chooses between L and R.

Compute two Bayesian Nash equilibria of this game.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

Player 1's strategy consists of two actions, one specifying what to do when $\theta=0$, the other when $\theta=3$. Let $XY$ denote the strategy "choose $X$ if $\theta=0$ and choose $Y$ if $\theta=3$. Hence, player 1 has four pure strategies: $\{TT,TB,BT,BB\}$.

To find a (pure strategy) BNE, we first conjecture that player 1 follows one of the four strategies, call it $s_1$. Then we derive player 2's best response. Lastly we check if $s_1$ is a best response to $s_2$; if it is, $(s_1,s_2)$ is a BNE, if not, we move on to player 1's next strategy and repeat the process.

Alternatively, we can create the [Bayesian normal form](http://econ.ucsb.edu/%7Egrossman/teaching/Econ171/Bayesian_Nash_Equilibrium-ho.pdf#page=14):

\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
&L&R\\\hline
TT&2,2&0,\frac12(0+3)\\\hline
TB&\frac12(2+3),\frac12(2+0)&\frac12(0+1),\frac12(0+1)\\\hline
BT&\frac12(0+2),\frac12(0+2)&\frac12(1+0),\frac12(1+3)\\\hline
BB&\frac12(0+3),0&1,1\\\hline
\end{array}

From here it's easy to verify that the only two pure strategy BNEs are $(TB,L)$ and $(BB,R)$.